# How to print class properties on the console?

Tags: c#, class, properties, console

I'd like to know how to print class properties on the console?

I found a relevant topic and I ran the code.It should be work, but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
public class Function //simple example
{
    public double [] Addition(double[] parameter1, double[] parameter2)
     {
          return 0;
     }
}

System.ComponentModel

foreach(PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Function))
{
    string name=descriptor.Name;
    object value=descriptor.GetValue(Function);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}",name,value);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Such way:

```
public static string PrintPropreties(object obj)
{
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj))
            {
                string name = descriptor.Name;
                object value = descriptor.GetValue(obj);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", name, value);
            }
}
```

Comment: @ Denis K. I saw this code.In this code the parameter is object not class.I don't understand the difference between object and class. I changed object by class and ran in c# but TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(class)found nothing

Comment: Let me explain the difference of class and object. Will try to do it simple. Class is a description of further objects that will be created using this class. It contains description of properties, methods etc. Object is an instance of class. Doing "ClassName objName = new ClassName()" you're creating instance of ClassName with pre-defined rules (properties/methods etc.). Regarding this example, please note that C#-methods can't get a class as parameter, only objects. We have type 'object' as a parameter, which is base for all classes, so this method can get any object of any class.